# android - Webview not showing content properly of Facebook URL

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I have an application in which I'm passing this URL to `WebView`.
[Facebook URL](https://www.facebook.com/androidindia)

But the `WebView` is not displaying the page correctly.
The default android browser is displaying the content correctly.

Code

```
WebSettings wsettings = webView.getSettings();
wsettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
wsettings.setSupportZoom(false);
wsettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);       
webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
wsettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
wsettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wsettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
wsettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wsettings.setAppCachePath("");
wsettings.setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");
wsettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);     
wsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.clearCache(true);
```

Please see the below screen shot for reference.

[image: Android Webview] [image: Android Browser]

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution for this by removing the below code.

```
wsettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
wsettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
wsettings.setAppCachePath("");
wsettings.setUserAgentString("AndroidWebView");
wsettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);     
wsettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webView.clearCache(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this options in your  WebView code:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);         
    } else {
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    }
```

In my case, Facebook works perfectly. 
Regards

Comment: Not have this setting     `mWebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);` . try to add

Comment: The method setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority) from the type WebSettings is deprecated

Comment: Try this: `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 8) {
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        }`